# perl/awk/sed/bash scripting: Multiple indent levels with multiple markers

Tags: perl, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to several levels indent a file based on a marker.
The marker argument only signifies that the next word on the same
line is a second level marker. Based on this second level marker,
I'd like to indent everything up until the next occurrence of that
second level marker.

The reason I'm trying to do this is for debugging another application. I'm printing out data at the top and before returns of every function (and several things in between).

Thanks in advance!

Usage would be something like this:
./script.sh file marker

**Example data:**

```
data
thismarker m1
thismarker m2
data
data
thismarker m2
data
data
thismarker m1
data
```

**Desired output of ./script.sh file thismarker:**

```
data
data
thismarker m1
 thismarker m2
      data
      data
 thismarker m2
 data
 data
thismarker m1
data
```

Here is what I have so far. I'm currently using awk but I'll be happy with anything that works. It doesn't work with multiple levels though and I don't know how to use mymarkertwo instead of what I'm currently doing - hard coding hcmarkertwo.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                      

file_path=$1                                                                     
markerone=$2                                                                     

 cat ${file_path} | awk -v mone="$markerone" '                                    
    BEGIN {                                                                  
            get_out=0;                                                       
            myfunc="";                                                       
    } {                                                                      

            if ( /${mone}/ ) {                                               
                    mymarkertwo = $2                                         
            }                                                                

            if ( /hcmarkertwo/ ) {                                           
                    get_out=0                                                
                    print $0                                                 
                    getline                                                  

                    do {                                                     
                            if ( /hcmarkertwo/ ) {                           
                                    get_out = 1                              
                                    print $0                                 
                                    getline                                  
                            } else {                                         
                                    $0 = "\t"$0                              
                                    print $0                                 
                                    getline                                  
                            }                                                
                    } while ( get_out == 0 )                                 
            }                                                                
    print $0                                                                 
}
'
```

Comment: Important question: do your markers + labels need to occur in matching pairs? Could both nested levels of indentation via `m1` and `m2` opening markers be terminated by the top level marker `m1` occurring a second time? (If not, then the extra `m1` and `m2` labels are redundant.)

Comment: Using `getline` is usually wrong (it is in this case) - read and fully understand http://awk.info/?tip/getline if you're considering using it in future.

Comment: Thanks everyone for some great answers! Yes, the markers and labels always occur in matching pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 == marker {
    if ($2 == markerId[depth]) {
        --depth
        nextIndent = --indent
    }
    else {
        markerId[++depth] = $2
        nextIndent = indent + 1
    }
}
{
    printf "%*s%s\n",indent,"",$0
    indent = nextIndent
}
```

.

```
$ cat file
data
thismarker m1
thismarker m2
data
thismarker m1
data
data
thismarker m1
data
thismarker m2
data
data
thismarker m1
data
```

.

```
$ awk -v marker="thismarker" -f tst.awk file
data
thismarker m1
 thismarker m2
  data
  thismarker m1
   data
   data
  thismarker m1
  data
 thismarker m2
 data
 data
thismarker m1
data
```

Note that I modified your sample input file to show a case where you have `m1` within the scope of `m2` within the scope of a previous `m1` as that can typically happen with function calls and it makes a solution more complicated than if it doesn't need to be accounted for. The currently posted `sed` solution will fail given that input, I don't have `perl` on my current UNIX box and I couldn't begin to guess at what the currently posted perl incantation says so I've no idea if that'd work or not - try it if you have perl.

Answer (score 2):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne '
    ($m) = $_ =~ /thismarker (\S+)/;
    pop(@M), $m = "" if $m && @M && $M[-1] eq $m;
    print +("   " x @M), $_;
    push @M, $m if $m;
  ' file.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-l`: Enable line ending processing, specifies line terminator
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){..}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `$m` contains current line's matched marker: `'m1'` or `'m2'`
- `@M` contains a stack of matched markers.

Comment: `one-liner`? I installed perl 5.14.4 on cygwin to try the above and got `syntax error at -e line 3, near "=  if"` `syntax error at -e line 4, at EOF`. Some meaningful variable names might improve the readability, right now the script is complete hieroglyphics to those of us who don't know perl.

Comment: Nice catch.  In moving from windows to unix style, I failed to translate my single quoted strings to double quoted.  This is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manage a stack of levels in order to process this properly. In pseudocode

```
line <- file.read
if line.words[0] == "thismarker"
    if line == stack.top
      stack.pop
      print(indent=stack.size) line
    else
      print(indent=stack.size) line
      stack.push(line)
    endif
 else
   print(indent=stack.size) line
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/thismarker m1/,/thismarker m1/{
   /thismarker m1/!s/^/   /
   /thismarker m2/,/thismarker m2/{
      /thismarker m2/!s/^/   /
      }
   }' YourFile
```

same concept if several level (just add a new section before the end of last level)

```
/thismarker mX/,/thismarker mX/{
   /thismarker mX/!s/^/   /
   }
```

Explanation:

Between 2 marker of same reference (`/thismarker mX/,/thismarker mX/`) [marker are not on the same line, it's mandatory but request specify it by it's structure], for each line without the specific marker (`/thismarker mX/ !`), substitute the beginning of the line with 3 space (`s/^/   /`).
The second level is done by the same way but inside the "loop" of first level. A thrd level should do the same inside the "loop" of second level, etc ...

Comment: added in post directly